# Please help identify mystery seeds

Tags: seeds

I’ve been finding these seeds for years on our small property in Ventura CA (climate zone 10b) and decided I should figure out what plant they are from. They are dark brown, shiny, hard, 1 cm in length and ~6 mm on the wider end, ovoid in shape.[image]

Comment: the best way to identify a seed is to have it sprout

Comment: I was thinking about that! I’ll give it a shot. Seems like I should scarify and soak it—I’ll try germinating it in a baggie.